# Got an AttributeError while trying to scrape data(using beautiful soup)

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

here is the part of code where I faced an issue -

```
exp_section = soup.find('section', {'id': 'experience-section'})
exp_section = exp_section.find('ul')
div_tag = exp_section.find('div')
a_tag = div_tag.find('a')
```

***Error -***

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-83105bd27260> in <module>
      1 exp_section = soup.find('section', {'id': 'experience-section'})
----> 2 exp_section = exp_section.find('ul')
      3 div_tag = exp_section.find('div')
      4 a_tag = div_tag.find('a')
      5 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Any suggestions would be appreciable, Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: `soup.find('section', {'id': 'experience-section'})` is returning None. you can check it by `print(exp_section)`. Essentially what is happening is `None.find`

Comment: so what should i do now?...but sir the YT video tutorial from where I was following his same code runs and didn't gave any error, but in case of mine, it gives error

Comment: The html on the site may have changed. You will need to inspect the page element and make sure that the `<section>` tag is used and that the `id` that you want is `experience-section`

Comment: Ok sir, I got it, thanks for your valuable suggestions. May God bless u.

Comment: sir sorry to disturb you again, for the previous error I changed `section` to `section id` and it works but it shows me the same error in the next line i.e `exp_section = exp_section.find('ul')`. please suggest

Comment: Are there any `<ul>` tags nested under the `<section>` because if you are getting the same error I am guessing the answer is no.

Comment: ok sir wait, let me comment down the inspect part, sir I'm trying beautiful soup for the first time, so please take out some time to help me :)

Comment: No problem. Can you also provide the link to the website?

Comment: Sir unfortunately i didnt understand whether `<ul>` is nested or not but I noticed the `<ul>` tag opened and closed at last `</ul>`

Comment: sir here's the link - https://www.linkedin.com/in/tresayles/

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look.

Comment: Ok.. Sir just a request, for now, I am logging off , Iwill not be able to read your comment now, So I will again continue this tomorrow morning, sir if I get any issues and reply you tomorrow morning , whenever you will get time sir please try to co-operate with me to complete this. Thank you sir, Have a good day!!!

Comment: Sir have you checked?

Comment: @It_is_Chris Sir, please reply